# How to create a test project to UT a windows phone 8 project?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, mstest

I cannot find a way to create a unit test project to test a Windows Phone 8 application. Is there a way to create it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed [Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188) ? This update now includes Unit Test projects for windows phone projects.

Prior to the update people could use the [Windows Phone Toolkit Test Framework](https://nuget.org/packages/WPToolkitTestFx) available from nuget.

Comment: Thanks mate! That was the solution! You rock.